# Failed to send email from my desire domain using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, mail-server

I am writing script to send email from my domain using nodmailer package, my code is below:-

```
    /************send email **************/



 var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
         var transporter = createTransport('smtp://admin@digieasynow.com:paxxxxxxxxx
         @mail.digieasynow.com');
         var mailOptions = {
         from: '"Tester " admin@digieasynow.com', 
         to: 'example@gmail.com', 
         subject: 'Hello ✔', 
         text: 'Hello world ', 
         html: 'Hello world ' 
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error, info){
        if(error){
        return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        });


        /**End code here************/
```

On running, it gives the error below:

> Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: mail.digieasynow.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:.webhostbox.net, DNS:webhostbox.net"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to upgrade to a wildcard SSL certificate (that covers *.digieasynow.com). So that you can use as many subdomains as you wish.